# Broken wording in comment field hint

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface, help-text

As you can see below, we're missing some words.

[image]

User-agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Fixed in the code, will be fixed in the UI after the next deployment

Comment: My bad, didn't search thoroughly. VTCd to dupe.